# List of Objects, update if found otherwise add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have the code below which works:

```
List<XXTJobTableModel> xjobs = filexxts.GroupBy(x=> x.job)
            .Select(fx => new JobTableModel
            {
                job_no = fx.First().job,
                emps = fx.GroupBy(x=>x.emp_id).Select(x => new EmployeeTableModel
                {
                    eid = x.First().emp_id,
                    heds = x.GroupBy(h => h.HED).Select(h => new HEDModel
                    {
                        hed = h.First().HED,
                        hours = h.Sum(c => c.HOURS),
                        amt = h.Sum(c => c.AMOUNTRATE)
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

public class JobTableModel
{
    public string job_no { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeTableModel> emps { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeTableModel
    {
        public string emp_id { get; set; }
        public List<HEDModel> heds { get; set; }
    }

public class THEDModel
    {
        public string hed { get; set; }
        public decimal hours { get; set; }
        public decimal amt { get; set; }
    }
```

I have another `List<XXTJobTableModel> yjobs` already loaded from another data source.  What I would like to do, if the job_no is not found in yjobs, then add the job (with employee and he data) to yjobs.  If the job_no is found in yjobs, and the emp_id is not found in the Employee table for that job, then add the employee (and hed data) to that jobs.  If the employee is found in that job, then just add the HED data to the employees list.

I do not have a preference if I somehow merge xjobs and yjobs or if I load the xjobs directly into the yjobs list.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a very concise set of LINQ statements to do this merge operation or just any solution at all?  What I would do is loop through one set and use LINQ to compare each item to the other set, and add items resulting from the comparison to a third set.  Problems like this you have to decompose into manageable pieces, and then recompose it into a larger solution once the smaller pieces are working.  Make an attempt and if you get stuck someone on here will surely be able to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I could definitely loop, I was wondering if there was a more consise or better performing option.

Comment: There usually is a better performing option for something like this, but I tend to follow the approach of getting something to work first, then figure out how to do it the right, better, faster way.